# yasnippet for org-mode templating : elisp list type problem

Tags: yasnippet

I want to use yasnippet to create a generic template for my org-mode files including latex export classe (letters, memos, articles, etc...)

It's not that complicated, but I would like Yasnippet to offer me to choose from the list of latex classes I have configured myself with `(add-to-list 'org-latex-classes ...)`.

Therefore I introduced in my snippet the following line:

`#+LATEX_CLASS: ${2:$$$(yas-choose-value '(org-latex-class))}`

However, it seems that the variable is not recognized as a `stringp` :

`yas--move-to-field: Wrong type argument: stringp, (sequencep org-latex-class)`

Is there a way in *elisp* to convert `sequencep` to `stringp` ? Could it solve the problem ?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a list with the class names only:

```
#+LATEX_CLASS: ${2:$$(yas-choose-value (mapcar #'car org-latex-classes))}
```

Comment: perfect! thanks a lot !